# Java Json Parser array

Tags: java, arrays, json

This is my JSON String I succesfully load with my java code [result].

```
{"result":[
{
"opened_at":"2017-02-06 10:48:55",
"sys_updated_by":"user",
"state":"6"
},
{
"opened_at":"2017-02-06 12:20:43",
"sys_updated_by":"user2",
"state":"1"
},
{
"opened_at":"2017-02-06 15:32:34",
"sys_updated_by":"user3",
"state":"1"
}
]
}
```

This is the part where I save my JSON data in a JSONArray.

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("result");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
            String opened_at = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("opened_at");
            String sys_updated_by = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("sys_updated_by");
            String state = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("state");

        }
```

How can I print for example opened_at from user2 in console (using System.out.println())?

Comment: I have a question for you. This data can be accesed  multiply times from one user? Or just one time. Because you can use a map for this solution. For each iteration you will add the user String as key and the value of the Date as a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do I access for example opened_at from user2?**

```
java.util.Map<String , Object> myMap = new java.util.HashMap<>();

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        String opened_at = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("opened_at");
        String sys_updated_by = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("sys_updated_by");
        String state = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("state");

        // your CATCH
        myMap.put( sys_updated_by , arr.getJSONObject(i) ); 
    }

// IF YOUR ARE HARDCODING ACCESS
try
{
     System.out.println( ( (JSONObject)myMap.get("user") ).getString("opened_at") + ((JSONObject)myMap.get("user2")).getString("opened_at") );
}
catch(Exception any){}
```

Let sys_update_by key-value, BECOME THE KEY for your references towards the JSONObject for all the interested fields and later on let it help you to retrieve your interested records, simply by specifying the username in the hash map, sorry for a million updates, I will surely like to discuss how this is not the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, in the `for` loop, you just need to check the value of `sys_updated_by` and get corresponding value for `opened_at`:

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("result");
String opened = null;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String sys_updated_by = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("sys_updated_by");
    if("user2".equals(sys_updated_by)){
        opened = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("opened_at");
        break; //No need to iterate anymore
    }
}
System.out.println(opened);
```

Comment: dont you think its unnecessary to access `opened_at` for those whose `sys_updated_by` is not `user2`.

Answer (score 0):

Its much simple when you use `for-each loop`, and then check if it is `user2` store value of `opened_at` is some String and break out of loo.

```
 String openedAt = "";
 for(JOSNObject object : arr){
       if(object.getString("sys_updated_by").equals("user2")){
             openedAt = object.getString("opened_at");
             break;
       }
 }
 System.out.println(openedAt);
```